# even though fetch data is transformed into array, i cannot access those elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch

After fetching some date from external API using this code

```
let fetchedData = [];

fetch(api)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => JSON.parse(res.response))
    .then(arr =>  arr.map(e => fetchedData.push(e)) )
    .catch(err => err);
```

`fetchedData` is populated without any problem, at that moment data inside look like this

```
    {
        Key: '0',
        Record: {
            a: 'a0',
            b: 'b0'
        }
    },
    {
        Key: '1',
        Record: {
            a: 'a1',
            b: 'b1'
        }
    },
    {
        Key: '2',
        Record: {
            a: 'a2',
            b: 'b2'
        }
    }
```

for `console.log(fetchedData)` chrome tools display something like that:

```
[]
0: {Key: "0", Record: {…}}
1: {Key: "1", Record: {…}}
2: {Key: "2", Record: {…}}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

but if I want to access and extract this array like `console.log(fetchedData[0])`
then i shows as `undefined`
or `console.log(fetchedData.length)` shows `0`

but in the same script next call to `console.log(fetchedData)` shows normal array like previously

as a result in chrome tools i have

```
array
undefined
array
```

using code mentioned earlier

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you are doing an asynchronous operation, fetch returns a promise, so async means it will run after sync code runs: in this example it will run after `js let fetchedData = [];` runs. if that makes sense.

To handle this situation you could call this fetch operation inside a 
`js componentDidMount() {}` or `js useEffect(() => {})`

This is an example, but try it @wokadakow with your data and check the result!

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function AsyncData() {
   // Here goes your async data, just replace it 
// this is fake data 
    return await [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'john'
    }]
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncData()
    .then((data) => setData(data))

  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> TEST DATA </h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map(d => {
           return <li key={d.id}> {d.name} </li> 
      })}
      </ul>

    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait until your fetch is done either by using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) or by adding your `console.log` call into another `then` method:

```js
let fetchedData = [];

fetch(api)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => JSON.parse(res.response))
    .then(arr =>  arr.map(e => fetchedData.push(e)) )
    .then(arr =>  console.log(arr) )
    .catch(err => err);
```